# Symfony 4 - Console exception event listener

Tags: symfony, exception, command-line

I try to handle an exception from a Symfony console command in a Symfony 4 project.

This is my event listener in services.yaml:

```
kernel.event_listener:
        class: App\Application\EventListener\ExceptionListener
        arguments:
            - '@logger'
            - '@jms_serializer'
            - '@translator.default'
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.exception, method: onConsoleException }
```

What is the tag for this treatment?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The correct configuration is this:

```
kernel.event_listener:
        class: App\Application\EventListener\ExceptionListener
        arguments:
            - '@logger'
            - '@jms_serializer'
            - '@translator.default'
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: console.error }
```

And your exception listener:

```
namespace App\EventListener;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Event\ConsoleErrorEvent;

class ExceptionListener
{
    public function onConsoleError(ConsoleErrorEvent $event) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for you help @iiirxs